# Xperia M4 Aqua loop-crashes infinitely when trying to connect to my wifi network

Tags: sony-xperia, crashes

This morning I woke up and dropped my xperia down to the floor. When I would connect to my wifi network, my xperia would loop-crash infinitely. My xperia runs on Marshmallow (6.0.1)

To fix this situation, I used [Xperia PC Companion](https://support.sonymobile.com/gb/xperia-companion/) to repair and reset it. Yet, any time I would connect to my wifi, my xperia would loop-crash infinitely.

The situation became quite irrecoverable applicatively.

Comment: Dropping it to the floor may have broken somthing inside the phone, this is definitely an hardware problem. You should take it to a repair shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, I'd think dropping the xperia might have unconnected some hardware inside, most likely hardware linked to the wifi.

I watched the following videos to get more knowledge about what is inside that sealed water resistant phone.

- https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=xperia+m4+disassembly
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIvllLIefxcac
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-QRcGrUK8M

From those videos, I planned I'd open my phone with an airdryer and small screw drivers. It's more sketch than what is suggested in the videos, but the phone is 2 years old already and I don't plan on keeping it many years longer.

So, I opened the phone and it was a scary experience. Hopefully, I managed not to screw up much of the glue setup. Like in the videos, I disassembled the battery and the bottom part of the phone in order to get to unplug and replug several components to make sure they are properly plugged.

I put the cover back on the phone and it sticked ok... From now on, I won't put it into water anymore, I can live with that.

Booted it back up and set it up. It works just as new.